# How to manage statuses associations in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Say for example I have an Order and Status.

Status:

1. status_id: 1 , status_name: Open
2. status_id: 2 , status_name:Closed

Order:

1. order#: 1, status_id: 1

How to manage the association in Ruby on Rails?

Would the following code is the best choice?

---

```
class Status < ActiveRecord::Base

      has_many :orders

end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

      belongs_to :status

end
```

Comment: Quite simply, yes your code is correct. Only comment is to make sure your status table id column is called `id` not `status_id` - rails will assume the former.

Comment: I agree, @Matt . the problem is that status doesn't really has many orders, and the order not really belongs to the status, but if this is the best way..

Comment: I don't follow - why do you feel that the status doesn't have many orders? Can you have more than one order at a time that are "Open"? If so, the "Open" status has many orders that belong to it. 

What makes you feel otherwise?

Comment: @Matt, It is a matter of terminology, but I understand your claim ..

Comment: It's not terminology, its a fundamental of relational data and worth understanding/getting used to :)

Answer (score 1):

For you problem I suggest the use of Enums. For this you will have a class `Order` like this:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    enum status: [:open, :closed]
end
```

This will give you the ability to call methods like:

```
order = Order.new
order.closed? # => false
order.status # => "open"
```

Remember, when you define an enum, the order matters. So, defining:

```
enum status: [:open, :closed]
```

is different from:

```
enum status: [:closed, :open]
```

Comment: Thanks @psantos , but this is just an example. I want to be able to manage the statuses as table, with flags and so on..

Comment: create a new model for statuses

Comment: Table statuses and table order? Seems odd to me because its 1:1 association. I would create an instance variable ( @var ) and store there the name of the status.

Comment: @David when you say, manage statuses, you are talking about edit, delete, create statuses?

Comment: Yes, @psantos. This is the meaning